# Return formatted string from variadic function

Tags: c++

I am having a variadic having function body as below -

```
char * ReturnMessage1(const char *format,...)
{
    va_list vl;
    int i = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    va_start( vl, format );

    switch( format[i] ) {   // Type to expect.
    case 'i':
        {
            int ii = va_arg(vl, int );
            ss << ii;
        }
        break;

    case 'f':
        {
            double f = va_arg(vl, double );         
            ss << f;
        }
        break;

    case 'c':
        {
            char c = va_arg(vl, char );          
            ss << c;
        }
        break;

    case 's':
        {
            char * str = va_arg(vl, char * );            
            ss << str;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    va_end( vl );
    return const_cast<char*>(ss.str().c_str());
}
```

Now I variable sis expected to compile all the arguments and form a string statement and return it. BUt it is returning a garbage string.Where am I going wrong??

Comment: `return const_cast<char*>(ss.str().c_str());` = bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer that you're returning is not valid after the function returns, because the object which it pointed is local to the function body and dies when you leave the function.

You need a dynamic string, best done with the ready-made `std::string` class:

```
std::string ReturnMessage1(const char *format,...)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;

    //

    return ss.str();
}
```